# ARM32 embedded: Using timers in polled mode

Tags: timer, arm, polling

Working with NXP LPC1768 32 bit ARM. Attempting to use a timer in polled mode, ie. no interrupts. The chip documentation is not clear on the location of a match flag, it only mentions an ‘interrupt-on-match flag’. My testing so far has been to assume that the interrupt flag also functions for polled operation, however my test program is not working, it appears that resetting the interrupt flag (by writing a 1 to the bit position as per the datasheet) is not occurring as it should. OTOH, there could be other reasons why things aren’t working. The uncertainty regarding the flag is making the job of diagnosis a lot harder.

Can someone advise whether and where there is a match flag that can be used in polled mode, and how to clear it? Thanks

Comment: Assuming this is one of the regular timers, how have you configured the relevant TxMCR?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue with using an interrupt flag this way - you should be sure to actually enable the interrupt-on-match feature (according to what the LPC176x manual, that would appear to mean setting MRxI in TxMCR as appropriate) because there's probably no guarantee it'll work as expected otherwise. The only difference after that is that instead of enabling the IRQ at the NVIC and reading TxIR from a handler when it fires, you leave the IRQ masked and read TxIR from your polling loop; it's not like the peripheral can tell the difference.

Alternatively, it looks like the External Match Register can also be configured appropriately to do precisely what you want. The manual even goes as far to point out:

> Note that match conditions may be used internally without the use of a device pin.

That said, you're polling a *timer* - why bother setting up a hardware match condition and polling some other register when you can simply poll the counter value directly? That's the typical way it's done.